# Cloud Shadow Removal for Sentinel-2

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, cloud-cover

I am trying to classify my study area with a RandomForest classifier, using Sentinel-2 Surface Reflectance images. This classification gave me an accuracy of about 87%. I calculated the misclassified points and below are its results.

```
Mangrove Misclassified Points
FeatureCollection (303 elements, 0 columns)
Water Misclassified Points
FeatureCollection (989 elements, 0 columns)
Other Misclassified Points
FeatureCollection (242 elements, 0 columns)
All Misclassified Points
FeatureCollection (1534 elements, 0 columns)
```

As you can see, so many points are getting misclassified. It is because of many shadows appearing.

I looked into [example](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/sentinel-2-s2cloudless), to remove the clouds and their shadows, but I am finding it very difficult to get my head around it.

I applied the below snippet

```
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}
```

This gave the misclassified points as

```
Mangrove Misclassified Points
FeatureCollection (282 elements, 0 columns)
Water Misclassified Points
FeatureCollection (986 elements, 0 columns)
Other Misclassified Points
FeatureCollection (269 elements, 0 columns)
All Misclassified Points
FeatureCollection (1551 elements)
```

The misclassified points increased, when it is expected to reduce.

Please guide me in understanding how I can incorporate it into my code, to improve the accuracy and minimize the misclassification points

Here is my implementation [GEE](https://code.earthengine.google.com/ad52929b41272c51cd0447cc4325d16c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually use the following to obtain *clear sky* composites:

```
// Generate 'clear_sky' Sentinel-2 images using SCL.
    var s2_clear_sky = function(image){
      var scl = image.select('SCL');
      var clear_sky_pixels = scl.eq(4).or(scl.eq(5)).or(scl.eq(6)).or(scl.eq(11));
      return image.updateMask(clear_sky_pixels);
    };
    
    // Map 's2_clear_sky' function over the imageCollection.
    var s2_data = s2_data.map(s2_clear_sky);
```

It removes 0-no data, 1-satured or defective, 2-dark area pixels, 3-cloud shadows, 7-unclassified, 8- cloud medium probability, 9-cloud high probability, 10- thin cirrus according to the SCL product: https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/technical-guides/sentinel-2-msi/level-2a/algorithm

Comment: This really worked like a gem, but I wonder how to classify the white patches it has left behind on my classified image. How can I classify them into my gcps?

Comment: Try not to remove the 7-Unclassified pixels by modifying the following line: var clear_sky_pixels = scl.eq(4).or(scl.eq(5)).or(scl.eq(6)).or(scl.eq( 7)).or(scl.eq(11)). If that doesn't work, you should try to fill in the gaps with images from nearer dates. You can't classify a pixel without data. You must fill the gaps with a linear interpolation, for example. You should open another query with this.

Comment: I tried the modification you provided, but did not work. As suggested, I will open another query regarding this. Thankyou.

Comment: I have another doubt. How can we handle the cloud cover for Landsat 8?

Comment: I'm not an expert in Landsat imagery and I have not worked with these images from GEE. But read GEE documentación: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/landsat