# How to classify white patches that were left after cloud removal, using Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to classify my study area with a RandomForest classifier, using Sentinel-2 Surface Reflectance images. From my previously raised query regarding [cloud removal](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/426571/cloud-shadow-removal-for-sentinel-2), I was able to resolve the issue of cloud cover, but it has left white patches on my classified image.

Please find my [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/8a3354cf14113576f3c94458a377eb95) for reference

Update:
I have tried using the Interpolation method to solve this issue as shown in [Spatial Thoughts](https://spatialthoughts.com/2021/11/08/temporal-interpolation-gee/#more-6094)

```
var days = 30

// For each image in the collection, we need to find all images
// before and after the specified time-window

// This is accomplished using Joins
// We need to do 2 joins
// Join 1: Join the collection with itself to find all images before each image
// Join 2: Join the collection with itself to find all images after each image

// We first define the filters needed for the join

// Define a maxDifference filter to find all images within the specified days
// The filter needs the time difference in milliseconds
// Convert days to milliseconds
var millis = ee.Number(days).multiply(1000*60*60*24)
var maxDiffFilter = ee.Filter.maxDifference({
  difference: millis,
  leftField: 'system:time_start',
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
})

// We need a lessThanOrEquals filter to find all images after a given image
// This will compare the given image's timestamp against other images' timestamps
var lessEqFilter = ee.Filter.lessThanOrEquals({
  leftField: 'system:time_start',
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
})

// We need a greaterThanOrEquals filter to find all images before a given image
// This will compare the given image's timestamp against other images' timestamps
var greaterEqFilter = ee.Filter.greaterThanOrEquals({
  leftField: 'system:time_start',
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
})

// Apply the joins

// For the first join, we need to match all images that are after the given image.
// To do this we need to match 2 conditions
// 1. The resulting images must be within the specified time-window of target image
// 2. The target image's timestamp must be lesser than the timestamp of resulting images
// Combine two filters to match both these conditions
var filter1 = ee.Filter.and(maxDiffFilter, lessEqFilter)
// This join will find all images after, sorted in descending order
// This will gives us images so that closest is last
var join1 = ee.Join.saveAll({
  matchesKey: 'after',
  ordering: 'system:time_start',
  ascending: false})
  
var join1Result = join1.apply({
  primary: filtered,
  secondary: filtered,
  condition: filter1
})
// Each image now as a property called 'after' containing
// all images that come after it within the time-window
print(join1Result.first())

// Do the second join now to match all images within the time-window
// that come before each image
var filter2 = ee.Filter.and(maxDiffFilter, greaterEqFilter)
// This join will find all images before, sorted in ascending order
// This will gives us images so that closest is last
var join2 = ee.Join.saveAll({
  matchesKey: 'before',
  ordering: 'system:time_start',
  ascending: true})
  
var join2Result = join2.apply({
  primary: join1Result,
  secondary: join1Result,
  condition: filter2
})

// Each image now as a property called 'before' containing
// all images that come after it within the time-window
print(join2Result.first())


// Do the interpolation

// We now write a function that will be used to interpolate all images
// This function takes an image and replaces the masked pixels
// with the interpolated value from before and after images.

var interpolateImages = function(image) {
  var image = ee.Image(image)
  // We get the list of before and after images from the image property
  // Mosaic the images so we a before and after image with the closest unmasked pixel
  var beforeImages = ee.List(image.get('before'))
  var beforeMosaic = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(beforeImages).mosaic()
  var afterImages = ee.List(image.get('after'))
  var afterMosaic = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(afterImages).mosaic()

  // Interpolation formula
  // y = y1 + (y2-y1)*((t – t1) / (t2 – t1))
  // y = interpolated image
  // y1 = before image
  // y2 = after image
  // t = interpolation timestamp
  // t1 = before image timestamp
  // t2 = after image timestamp
  
  // We first compute the ratio (t – t1) / (t2 – t1)

  // Get image with before and after times
  var t1 = beforeMosaic.select('timestamp').rename('t1')
  var t2 = afterMosaic.select('timestamp').rename('t2')

  var t = image.metadata('system:time_start').rename('t')

  var timeImage = ee.Image.cat([t1, t2, t])

  var timeRatio = timeImage.expression('(t - t1) / (t2 - t1)', {
    't': timeImage.select('t'),
    't1': timeImage.select('t1'),
    't2': timeImage.select('t2'),
  })
  // You can replace timeRatio with a constant value 0.5
  // if you wanted a simple average
  
  // Compute an image with the interpolated image y
  var interpolated = beforeMosaic
    .add((afterMosaic.subtract(beforeMosaic).multiply(timeRatio)))
  // Replace the masked pixels in the current image with the average value
  var result = image.unmask(interpolated)
  return result.copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start'])
}

// map() the function to interpolate all images in the collection
var interpolatedCol = ee.ImageCollection(join2Result.map(interpolateImages))
```

this reduced the white patches, but not completely.

How do I remove them all?

Here is the updated [Code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/aee189dc7445317b0d8a4f7093e931ee)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you use the `COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY` collection to remove clouds for Sentinel 2. See [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/426237/getting-cloudfree-image-for-small-area-sentinel-2-using-google-earth-engine/426248#426248) question. Here's how it would look for you:

```
var cloudThreshold = 30
var filter = ee.Filter.and(
  ee.Filter.bounds(coringa),
  ee.Filter.date('2019-03-01', '2019-03-31')
)
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection(
    ee.Join.saveFirst('cloudProbability').apply({
        primary: ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR').filter(filter),
        secondary: ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY').filter(filter),
        condition: ee.Filter.equals({leftField: 'system:index', rightField: 'system:index'})
    })
).map(function (image) {
  var cloudFree = ee.Image(image.get('cloudProbability')).lt(cloudThreshold)
  return image.updateMask(cloudFree)
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/28674aff5ed44d3a0833e92efc24cdbe

You can tweak `cloudThreshold` to be more/less aggressive in the masking. If this still doesn't cut it, I'd look at a cloud scoring algorithm, to complement. [This](https://groups.google.com/g/google-earth-engine-developers/c/i63DS-Dg8Sg/m/Kc0knF9BBgAJ) is a EE Google Groups thread with lots of discussion about it.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. This method does remove the clouds but not completely. It works fine.